# Getting characters from indices in list of strings into one list of characters

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types, sublist

The title sounds like nonsense, but the example below will hopefully help.

Trying to write a big LINQ statement where, given a list of strings and a list of integers, it can gather a list of all of the characters in that list into one. Example:

indices:

```
{2,4}
```

possible:

```
{"hello","world"}
```

should give me:

```
{'l','o','r','d'}
```

from indices 2 and 4 in each string.

I think I'm a bit off, but here's a messy statement I was working on to give something to work from/correct:

```
var lettersToCheckOut = possible.Select(s => s.ToCharArray()).Select((c, index) => new
                        {
                            let = c,
                            ind = index
                        }).Where(c => indices.Contains(c.ind)).Select(c => c.let);
```

Comment: And your `Question here is`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that?

```
var chars = indices.SelectMany(i => words.Where(w => i < w.Length)
                                         .Select(w => w[i])).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", chars)); // lrod
```

The logic is as follows:

- For each index, I would like to go over all of the possible words, and gather characters.
- I must check, first, that the index is within the range of the current word.
- From each word, I take the character indexed as the current index.
- Using the `SelectMany` method, I get a collection of characters rather than a collection of `IEnumerable<char>`.

You can swap between `indices` and `words` to get the characters in different order:

```
var chars = words.SelectMany(w => indices.Where(i => i < w.Length)
                                         .Select(i => w[i])).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", chars)); // lord
```

Comment: The characters won't be in the same order as the example.  Not sure if that is important or not.

Comment: @juharr Good point. Note that to get them in the same order as in OP's example, you just need to swap between the `indices` and `words` in the code I provided, so that `words` will be in the outter loop, and `indices` in the inner loop (logically).

Comment: @YoryeNathan Beautiful, thank you. Also, order is not important, sorry, should have specified.

Comment: @Wilson I would suggest testing both variations for performance differences. They may differ when the sizes of the collections differ significantly, but not sure about that (nor in which way it would differ).

Comment: @YoryeNathan It'll be negligible. The collections will always be under 20 elements, and indices under 5 or so.

Comment: @Wilson Nothing to worry about, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has already been answered, but here's an alternate solution using Linq's query comprehension syntax. I personally find it more elegant, and am sharing it in case others do as well:

```
        var words = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
        var indexes = new[] { 2, 4 };

        //{ 'l', 'o', 'r', 'd' }
        var output = 
            from word in words
            from index in indexes
            where word.Length > index
            select word[index];
```